# Load local .mbtiles with maplibre-gl-js

Tags: javascript, cordova, mbtiles, maplibre-gl

I want to load a local .mbtiles (with vector tiles) with [maplibre-gl-js](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js) (in a Cordova app if it's important to know). As far as I understand, I should use the [addProtocol](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/blob/492bec58c5684609af8fba81ef01e5f5a3ef0711/src/index.js#L177) method. That works fine as I get my console.log, but I don't know how to load the tiles then...

This is my code:

```js
maplibregl.addProtocol('mbtiles', (params, callback) => {
  console.log('I get this log.');
  // but what to do here to get local mbtiles vector tiles loaded?
});
```

The style is defined like this:

```json
...
"sources": {
  "openmaptiles": {
    "type": "vector",
    "url": "mbtiles://map/data/test.mbtiles"
  }
},
...
```

Any help / hints appreciated :)

If you need more information, just feel free to ask.

P.S. I used [mapbox-gl-cordova-offline](https://github.com/oscarfonts/mapbox-gl-cordova-offline) before and tried to understand how this plugin loads the tiles, but I can't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I'm doing to achieve this:

```
maplibregl.addProtocol("custom", (params, callback) => {
// tileBuffer = get a arrayBuffer of a specific tile using params.url
    if (tileBuffer) {
        callback(null, tileBuffer, null, null);
    } else {
        let message = `Tile is not in DB: ${params.url}`;
        callback(new Error(message));
    }
    return { cancel: () => { } };
});
```

I'm using `cordova-sqlite-ext` in order to be able to use a pre-populated database in Cordova.
The style has a `tiles: [custom://database-name/{z}/{x}/{y}]` in order to know which tile to fetch.

Full code can be found here:
https://github.com/IsraelHikingMap/Site/blob/6aa2ec0cfb8891fa048b1d9e2a4fc7d4cbcc8c97/IsraelHiking.Web/src/application/services/database.service.ts

It's worth noting that I added the `addProtocol` method to maplibre especially for this purpose. :-)

Comment: I created a sveltekit demo app and used some of your code for the unzipping part. I also find your custom protocol interesting. I'm thinking I could make use of it for PWAs so that data can be retrieved from browser storage when off-line. What is the correct way to handle the case when a tile is not available?  Demo app: https://github.com/FunMiles/Planetiler_MapLibre_Sveltekit

Comment: How does this enable using the .mbtiles file directly? Seems like you still need something in the middle to translate the z,x,y requests?

Comment: @chrismarx yes, you need to write some code to fetch the tile using the url (which has x,y,z already "filled"). I use a database service for that in the browser which uses native capabilities in cordova/capacitor